# Subclassed UIAlertView not shown

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, uialertview

I'm subclassing UIAlertView. See code below. Nothing fancy, just set some bool if the alert is shown and reset it if it gets dismissed. But the alert never apepars on sreen. The screen gets dimmed and that's it. I get the following message in the app output:

```
Requesting the window of a view (<TestApp.AlertView: 0xfad7160; baseClass = UIAlertView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.
```

What does this message want to tell me? I'm calling base. What more can I do? 
Here's the class:

```
public sealed class AlertView : UIAlertView
    {
        public AlertView (string title, string message,UIAlertViewDelegate del, string cancelButtonTitle, params string[] otherButtons) : base(title, message, del, cancelButtonTitle, otherButtons)
        {
        }

        public AlertView() : base()
        {
        }

        public AlertView(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
        {
        }

        public AlertView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }


        public AlertView(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
        {
        }

        public override void Show ()
        {
            this.bIdleTimerWasRunning = AppDelegateBase.MainApplication.IsUIIdleTimerEnabled;
            AppDelegateBase.MainApplication.EnableUIIdleTimer(false);
            base.Show ();
        }

        private bool bIdleTimerWasRunning;

        public override void DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (int index, bool animated)
        {
            AppDelegateBase.MainApplication.EnableUIIdleTimer(this.bIdleTimerWasRunning);
            base.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (index, animated);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure (I need to test that further) but the default constructor for your `AlertView` works (small text-less, button-less popup appear).

From that you can *fake* the whole thing with something like:

```
public sealed class AlertView : UIAlertView
{
    public AlertView (string title, string message,UIAlertViewDelegate del, string cancelButtonTitle, params string[] otherButtons)
        : base ()
    {
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        Delegate = del;
        // add buttons
        CancelButtonIndex = AddButton (cancelButtonTitle);
        foreach (string s in otherButtons)
            AddButton (s);
    }
 ...
```

Hopefully that can unblock you :-)

Comment: Hm. okay. Thanks. Strange. Why would the default constructor work and the other one not?

Comment: My guess it that something does not get initialized properly (in that chain of call) and I kept a note about it (I got other things I want to complete right now ;-). You can fill a bug report on bugzilla.xamarin.com and I (or someone else) will post, future, findings on the issue. Otherwise (and if my memory does not fail me) I'll try to add this information back into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for filling (and posting the link back here)! I (or someone else) will post progress on the bug report and the final reason here :)